# Simplifying Sympy expressions as implicit functions of variables

Tags: math, sympy, simplify, mathematical-expressions, simplification

I am wondering if there is any way to simplify Sympy expressions by rewriting the expression in terms of an already defined variable, making Python collect the terms fitting with that variable's definition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [collect](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/simplify/simplify.html#collect)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried collect without luck, unfortunately. The case is that I have a huge mathematical expression and I am looking for a way for Python to represent parts of it as a function of the expressions' variables (say x), by scanning for every possible combination of said variables and nesting them into these functions (say p(x)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this doesn't quite exist as you describe it, but it's not hard to do what you want.

Firstly, there is the [`cse()` function](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#sympy.simplify.cse_main.cse), which pulls out common subexpressions as variables automatically. However, it will not use pre-defined variables if that is what you want. But if your goal is just to simplify the evaluation of an expression, and you don't really care what the intermediate expressions are, `cse` is your best bet.

One trick that you can use is to isolate a single part your subexpressions and substitute them. For example, say you had an expression `expr` containing `x + y`, and you wanted to replace `x + y` with `z`. Simply doing `expr.subs(x + y, z)` often works. But in some cases it won't because `subs` only replaces `x + y` if it finds it exactly in the expression.

A trick you can use instead is to "solve" (you can do it automatically with `solve` if you like) the substitution `z = x + y` for a single variable, like `x = y - z`, and replace that (`expr.subs(x, y - z)`). Since there is no ambiguity on where `x` appears like there was for `x + y`, this will replace it everywhere. You often then must `expand` the expression to get things to cancel out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out!